# Get only id of a my ManyToOne object

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have this mapping:

```
[Class(Table = "foo", Name = "Foo")]
public class Foo
{
    [Id(0, TypeType = typeof(long), Name = "Id", Column = "id")]
    [Generator(1, Class = "native")]
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }

    [ManyToOne(Class = "Bar", Column = "bar_id", NotNull = true)]
    public virtual Bar Bar { get; set; }
}

[Class(Table = "bar", Name = "Bar")]
public class Bar
{
    [Id(0, TypeType = typeof(long), Name = "Id", Column = "id")]
    [Generator(1, Class = "native")]
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }

    [Bag(0, Inverse = true, Table = "foo", Cascade = "save-update")]
    [Key(1, Column = "bar_id", ForeignKey = "fk_foo_bar_id")]
    [OneToMany(2, Class = "Foo")]
    public virtual IList<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
}
```

and I would like to do the SQL query:

```
SELECT bar_id FROM foo f WHERE f.id = 1
```

I know I can do

`Session.Get<Foo>(1).Bar.Id` however, it loads the `Bar` object and if it a very **HEAVY** object, my simple query, that only wants something that is inside the `foo` table is very slow. How should I do it ?

I thought about adding a property like this

```
[Property(Column = "bar_id", NotNull = true)]
public virtual long BarId { get; set; }
```

But I don't know if it is wrong or not, or if I should it differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally we did it like this:

```
public class FooToBarResult
{
    public string FooId { get; set; }
    public int BarId { get; set; }
}

IList<BlockToComponentResult> result = session
       .CreateSQLQuery(@"SELECT bar_id as BarId, id as FooId FROM `foo`")
       .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<FooToBarResult>())
       .List<FooToBarResult>();
```

My conclusion is that NHibernate is cool, if you do only what they want you to do, but as soon as you have some performance issue and want to optimize the query, you need to come back to SQL and the pain begins.

Answer (score 0):

NHibernate supports  [lazy properties](http://ayende.com/blog/4377/nhibernate-new-feature-lazy-properties). Check if that solves your problem.

Comment: Yes I know about lazy loading, but I cannot change that in my second Bar object. In fact I just don't understand my NHibernate force me to load the object Bar, for something that is inside my first object Foo...

Comment: it is not lazy loading, it is lazy properties... if you have bulky fields (not mappings ) you can mark as lazy. go and check the ayende's article on it.

Comment: sorry, I knew about this post, and I use it some other places in my code. My problem is that I cannot change the attributes to make properties as Lazy because it may break other code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Session.Load<Foo>(id)`.

NHibernate should be smart enough to realise it doesn't need to load `Bar` and generate a proxy version containing just its ID. It would only load Bar if you accessed another of its properties.

However `Session.Get()` [does not do this](http://ayende.com/blog/3988/nhibernate-the-difference-between-get-load-and-querying-by-id) since it uses caching. But if you were to change this to use `Session.Load<Foo>(id)`, you should see this behaviour.

Comment: do you mean .Load<Foo>(id) ? because here I don't know the id of Bar, this is what I want

Comment: and then, if I do Session.Load<Foo>(id).Bar.Id, do you think it won't load the Bar object, but only the Bar.Id property ?

Comment: I'm fairly sure. Check the actual type of the objects returned. They should be generated proxy types.

Comment: well, now, if I need to load a bunch of Foo object, with Session.CreateCriteria<Foo>().List<Foo>(), I am stuck with the fact that Bar is not lazy loaded :/ and I cannot change this behavior :/

Comment: I don't understand. Relations should all be lazy-loaded by default.

Comment: Well, sorry Bar is lazy loaded, but it loads ALL the object in once, and I only want the Id property.